# How to check if process is running in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to automatically check if a process is running or not and have to perform next steps accordingly. I had written a bash script but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if ps aux | grep [M]yProcessName > /dev/null
then
  echo "Running"
else
  echo "Not running"
fi
```

Is my `if` statement wrongly used?

Comment: Your `if` looks fine. Why don't you run it and find out yourself? It took me a minute to copy the if into a file and start it.

Comment: I did run it and its not working, that's why I asked

Comment: *How* is it "not working? What do you get when you remove the output redirection?

Comment: Ok, in my system it worked perfectly. It just says: "Not running". When I change MyProcessName to bash, it says: "Running".

Comment: Sorry, please close this question. My mistake.

Comment: @noMAD What you have works, but its better to use `if pgrep -f 'foo' >/dev/null; then ...`

Comment: @jordanm: Why is that better?

Comment: @noMAD because it is actually designed for exactly that, and doesn't spawn an additional subshell.

Comment: For future reference, posting a question with a meaningless "its not working" statement and no information about what "its not working" means makes it a very poor question that will probably cost you rep.

Comment: Also for future reference, `grep -q` works everywhere-that-matters nowadays.

Comment: If you have a file called `MyProcessName` in the current directory, the shell will expand the apparent wildcard in `[M]yProcessName`, yielding `MyProcessName`, in which case the `grep` will, again, match itself..  Single-quoting the regex will prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't want to know if a particular process (of known pid) is running (this can be done by testing if `/proc/1234/` exists for pid 1234) but if some process is running a given command (or a given executable).

Notice that the [kill(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/kill.2.html) syscall can be portably used to check if a given process is running (with a 0 signal, e.g. `kill(pid,0)`). From inside a program, this is a common way to check that a process of known pid is still existing and running (or waiting).

You could use the `pidof` command to find the processes running some executable, e.g. `pidof zsh` to find all the `zsh` processes. You could also use `killall -s 0 zsh`

And you might be interested by the `pgrep` utility and the `/proc` filesystem.

Answer (score 9):

```
ps aux | grep [M]yProcessName | grep -v grep
```

Comment: can you pls explain why 3 greps are required?

Comment: The `grep -v grep` filters out the line(s) that contain "grep". This is necessary because `ps aux | grep foo` will capture lines listing all the processes currently running that contain the string "foo", which includes the command itself! In other words, you will *always* have a line in your results, whether a `foo` process is running or not. Using `grep -v grep`, you will have 0 lines when no `foo` process is running, and you will only get the line(s) pertaining to actual `foo` processes, not your command.

Comment: This answer is wrong and should probably be removed. The `[M]` already takes care of filtering out the `grep` process, a second `grep` is NOT needed in this case. Pattern `[M]yProcessName` only matches string `MyProcessName`, whereas `grep` shows up as `grep [M]yProcessName` in the process list, thus it does not match and does not get included.

Answer (score 2):

Using -z to check if a string is empty or not, something like this could work:

```
line=$(ps aux | grep [M]yProcessName)
if [ -z "$line" ]
then
    echo "Not Running"
else
    echo $line > /dev/null
    echo "Rinnung"
fi
```

Comment: His first implementation is better. `grep` returns non-zero when it doesn't match, so test is not needed. The `[]` around the M eliminates the need for the `grep -v grep`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution:

```
if [ "$(ps aux | grep "what you need" | awk '{print $11}')" == "grep" ]; then ... elif [ ... ]; then ... else ... fi
```

This works fine in Debian 6. '{print $11}' is needed, because the sytem treats grep as a process as well

Comment: -1 This is horribly botched newbie code and inefficient to boot. It does not solve the OP's problem (which was unclear in the first place) and offers no additional functionality over the original, more elegant and correct code.

Answer (score 2):

```
processid =$(ps aux | grep 'ProcessName' | grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}')
```

The above command will give you the process id. Assign that process id to a variable and do this -->

```
if cat /proc/$processid/status | grep "State:  R (running)" > /dev/null
then
  echo "Running"
else
  echo "Not running"
fi
```

Comment: too late to revert my +1: there is is a problem in grepping for state "R (running)" because often what you think of as a running process will be in state "sleeping" when it is idle.

Comment: Ya. But the Question was to check if the process running or not.
One can extend the above code for his convenience. It was just to give a lead.

Answer (score 1):

```
SMBD=$(pidof smbd)
if [ "$SMBD" == "" ];
then
   /etc/init.d/samba start;
else
   /etc/init.d/samba restart;
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to explicitly mention a way [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13264571) alluded to, `pgrep` is the best way to do this by process name:

```
pgrep [M]yProcessName
```

If a process whose name matches "[M]yProcessName" is running, `pgrep` will print its PID to stdout and will exit with code `0`. Otherwise, it will print nothing and exit with code `1`.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, `ps aux | grep ProcessName` always get a line of that grep process like:

```
edw4rd     9653  0.0  0.0   4388   832 pts/1    S+   21:09   0:00 grep --color=auto ProcessName
```

So, the exit status is always 0. Maybe that's why your script doesn't work.

Comment: That's why the OP's `grep` uses a regex which doesn't match itself.

Answer (score 0):

return 0 means success while others failed

```
kill -0 `pid`; echo $?
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
ps aux | grep [M]yProcessName | grep -v grep
```

Comment: Writing `[M]y` instead of `My` here makes the `grep -v grep` unnecessary, because `[M]y` does not match itself.

Comment: Thanks @Zack :-) I will start using it this way :-) I also thinking that those [] around M were useless. Awesome workaround it is :-)